Wondering if I should just run 2 extended circuits or a sub panel for my shed
I have a shed that is about 50-60 feet from my house where the panel is located and we are planning on turning the shed into a little hangout spot. It is 10x14 and play to install a TV on the wall, have a plug in A/C unit and want to install outlets 4-6 outlets and have 4 recess lights. Still considering outside lighting as well since our lights on the house reach out that far.
What factors should I consider in making the choice between adding a sub panel in the shed or running two circuits from the house?

Opinions will be off-topic for this site, as you're going to get at least one and possibly another, centering on Yes or No. Better to tweak your question to something like "With these expected loads, what size wire should I run for a sub-panel, and how should I run it?" Then you can get a scope of your possible project and you can consider Yes or No for your own needs and budget.

You can't really ask "what's best for me" questions here.   Likely this question will be closed but if you change it to ask specific technical questions about how to implement or what's allowed, that would be better.

FWIW, and not specific to you: It depends what equipment and labor you have available.   If you have a machine that can slit and bury UF cable 2 feet deep without trenching and you can make do with a couple of 20A circuits, that would be a cheap approach.  If you have to dig a trench, that'll be the lion's share of the cost and then you should certainly install a subpanel via an oversized conduit and run a second conduit for low voltage.  Later if you want to use the shed as a workshop or put patio heaters outside it or whatever, you can do that easily.

Once you price out two circuits of 12 gauge copper plus what is needed in the shed, you might find a sub connected with 2-2-2-4(or smaller) Al be cost effective.

Welcome to DIY. As mentioned opinion questions are off-topic. I've edited your question slightly so that instead of asking "which is best" it asks "what factors should I consider." If that doesn't fit your intent, please edit the question again!

Made another edit to clarify the "what factors" angle. Vote to leave open.

If your installation is subject to NEC rules (and I infer that it is) then you'll want to know that NEC imposes a limit of a single circuit feeding a detached building like yours.
The "circuit" could be a multi-wire branch circuit. This looks and acts like two 120 volt circuits, up to 20 amps, but they are wired in a particular way. Some attention must be paid as to whether GFCI protection is required (it's still doable) and especially whether arc fault protection is required: availability of 2-pole ground, arc, and combo fault circuit breakers varies among panel brands. So this strategy may or may not be feasible for your situation. You'll need to find out which version of NEC is applicable and whether you have any local amendments that add or remove requirements in this area.
There's a little carve-out for outside lighting: if there's a switch in the house then you're allowed a "bonus" circuit for powering that lighting at the outbuilding, and whatever else may also be attached to it.
The loads you mentioned sound like they could potentially be coordinated to work with a single 20 A circuit, and definitely could on a two-pole 20 A MWBC circuit.
If you do choose to put a subpanel in the shed then you're free to have as many separate circuits as you desire, and dealing with AFCI and/or GFCI requirements may be easier. With a subpanel at the shed you'll also have to install a grounding electrode system (typically two ground rods), but will also need a ground conductor back to the main panel.
We can't give an opinion as to which solution fits your needs better, but hopefully this info equips you to make that decision yourself.
